# unable to import nvd3 guage chart JS file

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I need to implement guage chart and I am using NVD3 for that.

https://github.com/enplore/nvd3-charts

I tried to import js files mentioned in above link

but getting the following error,
**GET http://[ip]/nodejs/bower_components/nvd3/build/gaugeChart.js**

Comment: If you could post in the code and error (not just the links) it will be more likely that you'll get help

Comment: The error is :  
GET http://[ip]/nodejs/bower_components/nvd3/build/gaugeChart.js 404 (Not Found)
I am not able to import guageChart.js and hence not able to move forward.